# Mysql query for multiple array values

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, video

I have this query:

```
$relatedtags = $video->tags;
$relatedtagsagain = explode(",", $relatedtags);
$query_parts = array();
foreach ($relatedtagsagain as $item) {
$query_parts[] = "'%".mysql_real_escape_string($item)."%'";}
$string = implode(",", $query_parts);

$result = $cachedb->get_results("SELECT ".DB_PREFIX."videos.title,".DB_PREFIX."videos.id as vid,".DB_PREFIX."videos.thumb, ".DB_PREFIX."videos.views,".DB_PREFIX."videos.duration,".DB_PREFIX."users.name, ".DB_PREFIX."users.id as owner FROM ".DB_PREFIX."videos LEFT JOIN ".DB_PREFIX."users ON ".DB_PREFIX."videos.user_id = ".DB_PREFIX."users.id where ".DB_PREFIX."videos.tags LIKE {$query_parts[0]} OR ".DB_PREFIX."videos.tags LIKE {$query_parts[1]} limit 0,".get_option('related-nr')." ");
```

How can get results for more `$query_parts[] like $query_parts[2]` and `$query_parts[3]` or from all the array? using `LIKE $query_parts[]` wont work.

Comment: Make the query a variable and append to it.

Comment: Hi Chris, its beiond my coding skills.

Comment: `WHERE " . implode(' OR ', array_map(function($value) { return DB_PREFIX . "videos.tags LIKE {$value}"; }, $query_parts));` - or similar

Comment: Example ^^ https://eval.in/316203

Answer (score 0):

lets go back to the basic of programming, this can be solved in many ways, like using array_mapping(see comment of scrowler), loops and many more:

sample using foreach loop:

```
foreach ($relatedtagsagain as $item) {
  $query_parts[] = " videos.tags LIKE " . "'%". mysql_real_escape_string($item) . "%' ";
}
$parsed_query_parts = implode('OR', $query_parts);

$result = $cachedb->get_results("SELECT ".DB_PREFIX."videos.title,".DB_PREFIX."videos.id as vid,".DB_PREFIX."videos.thumb, ".DB_PREFIX."videos.views,".DB_PREFIX."videos.duration,".DB_PREFIX."users.name, ".DB_PREFIX."users.id as owner FROM ".DB_PREFIX."videos LEFT JOIN ".DB_PREFIX."users ON ".DB_PREFIX."videos.user_id = ".DB_PREFIX."users.id WHERE" . $parsed_query_parts . " limit 0,".get_option('related-nr')." ");
```